# How to make alexa wait for 3-4 seconds for user input else proceed

Tags: php, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am developing an alexa app for events to show. I am showing three events at the same time and if there is an artist associated with the event, alexa will ask user to say play if user wants to hear music. My issue is if I am keeping the session alive, alexa will ask the question and if user say nothing, it turns off and if I close the session, alexa asks the question and shut down.

Here is the sample code:

```
foreach($events as $key=>$event){
     $eventname = "abcd";
     $artistId  = '1';
     $artistName= "xyz";
     $speech =$eventname;
     $response = '{
         "version" : "1.0",
         "sessionAttributes": {
             "artistId": "'.$artistId.'",
             "artistName": "'.$artistName.'"
          },
          "response" : {
          "outputSpeech" : {
             "type" : "PlainText",
             "text" : "'.$speech.'"
          },
          "shouldEndSession" : false
      }
   }';
   echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to `<break time=\"0.6s\"/>`

Refer to this link [Using break in SSML](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#break)

```
<speak>
    There is a three second pause here <break time="3s"/> 
    then the speech continues.
</speak>
```

Comment: I am using php.. will this help me?

Comment: Because I changed as per document but alexa is just moving resulting timeout eveytime.

Comment: OK.. got it.. thanks a lot for sharing the document.

Comment: I have one more question.. is there any way i can get a input from user in between these pause... if we are getting input then proceed with input otherwise go for the next event.

Comment: hmmm.. good question... i don't think you can process to next event if user doesn't response.. :ask allows you to repeat your question but there has to be an user response.. with my knowledge .. answer is your question is no its not possible.. but you might to ask it as separate question on stackoverflow